# Shared Preferences gets lost

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm saving 2 string to shared preferences and once in a while, for some reason they get's deleted.. 
I know there's a couple of other questions here on stackoverflow about this, but non of them helped me..

Is there something wrong with the way i save to the shared preferences?

And does anybody know what's causing the problem, it has only happend like two times over like 2 weeks or something... so I can test it, to see if I've solved the promblem?

```
static void saveTitlePref(Context context, int mAppWidgetId, String text) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0).edit();
    editor.putString(PREF_PREFIX_KEY + mAppWidgetId, text);
    editor.apply();
}

static void saveSizePref(Context context, int mAppWidgetId, String size) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0).edit();
    editor.putString(PREF_SIZE_PREFIX_KEY, size);
    editor.apply();
}
```

I load them like this:

```
static String loadTitlePref(Context context, int mAppWidgetId) {

    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    String prefix = prefs.getString(PREF_PREFIX_KEY + mAppWidgetId, null);
    // If there is no preference saved, get the default from a resource
    if (prefix != null) {
        return prefix;
    } else {
        return context.getString(R.string.appwidget_prefix_default);
    }
}

static String loadSizePref(Context context, int mAppWidgetId) {

    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    String sizeprefix = prefs.getString(PREF_SIZE_PREFIX_KEY, null);
    // If there is no preference saved, get the default from a resource
    if (sizeprefix != null) {
        return sizeprefix;
    } else {
        return "24";
    }
}
```

Comment: use `editor.commit();` instead of `editor.apply();`

Comment: This looks fine, how are you reading these values?

Comment: @MMohsinNaeem hu. thought it was pretty much the same, but I'll try it, and see if it works, thanks..

Comment: @MMohsinNaeem That's not the solution, and will actually block the current thread until the commit finishes.

Comment: From [SharedPreferences#apply()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply%28%29): "it's safe to replace any instance of `commit()` with `apply()` if you were already ignoring the return value." (API 9+)

Comment: @DavidCaunt it is the problem!

Comment: Does anyone know what's causing this? so I can test to see if it has been fixed?

Comment: @Jakob Your `if (sizeprefix != null)` check is redundant, use `String sizeprefix = prefs.getString(PREF_SIZE_PREFIX_KEY, "24");`

Comment: @DavidCaunt I see, but when deleting the if "(sizeprefix ...  " and using your suggestion I get an error on my method saying: This method must return a result of type String

Comment: Oh! and now that I think about it, saying commit() instead of apply() might solve the problem, cause I looked in an earlier version of my app, which I think didn't have this bug, and in that one I use commit(), can't remember why I changed it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed `editor.apply();` to `editor.commit();`

Answer (score 0):

Are you using multiple processes or a single process?

What API level are you using? I know in API level 11, Google changed the default flags so that MODE_MULTI_PROCESS was no longer the default. Just a thought.

Comment: My min API is 12. Sorry I'm a beginner, by process you mean?

Comment: Ok, probably not the issue then. You can have more than one process running but it's not typical -- you'd have to explicitly set that up in your AndroidManifest.xml file

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the answear in your case, but I had a similar problem. The reason it "disapears" is that for some reason `String example = "notnull"` can not been compared using:

```
example != null;
```

This make it look like it is has disapeared but it has not. If you call this instead:

```
example.equals(null);
```

It will be able to recognice it. I know this does the opposite of the first one, but you figure it out. This may not be the answer in your case, but it is something you should try.

Comment: Now the prefs is not even being loaded.. just to be sure: you did mean i should replace: if (prefix != null) { with: if (prefix.equals(null)) {

Comment: Yes had a problem with that. I noticed that you used the first one in your code. Then I can not help you. You might consider setting a bounty on this question.